# html shows up as text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I'm trying to render html in my Rails application, but the html shows as plain text.

Here is my edit.erb file:

```
<form action="/posts/update">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= post.id %>"/>
  <input type="text" name="post[title]" value="<%= post.title %>"/>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="post[body]" id=""><%= post.body %></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

[image]

I use RubyMine as IDE.

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the filename to `edit.html.erb`.

With only `erb` Rails doesn't know you are tyring to render `html` and will render it as text.

Comment: I am using `erubis` gem, There is should be only `.erb`

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? erubis is default behaviour from Rails 3 and you don't have to include anything. Also my answer stays the same. The extension should be `.html.erb`.

Comment: @afurm Did you check atleast by changing it to edit.html.erb?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I think the problem with my IDE with whitespaces.

Comment: Solved. Problem was in my IDE with whitespaces.
Thank you @Arjan for you time.